# Minimal HTML/CSS to specify distinct color for each character of the text

Tags: html, css, colors

I need to specify a different color for each character of the text in an HTML page. The text is long and the generated HTML file size should be as small as possible. In other words, the color formatting tags used should be as minimal as possible. How do you suggest to perform this task?

Comment: What do you mean `specify a different color`? You want it to have some logic or be totally random?

Comment: @Itay, The colors are selected based on the pixels from a given photo. The aim is to see something like a watermark by looking at the whole block of the text.

Comment: How many colors do you have?

Comment: @Itay, the original bitmap is RGB565 which means 64K different colors are possible

Comment: Well, you can't use classes because it means you'll have to have 64K classes. You can use inline style with short tags like `i`, this way: `<i style="font-color=#AAAAAA">H</i>` but this would generate very large files. I would reconsider the entire need and way of action.

Comment: Just a little out of the box thinking but I'm sure you could store the colors in a javascript array, and the text in a char array (basically a string) and loop through the colors printing the corresponding character with the color to a `canvas` or using the heavy markup to add them to a `div`.

Comment: Use a monospace font and adjust the containers width appropriately and you could accomplish this feat with no real issues.

Comment: This would be trivial with JavaScript.

Comment: @rosscowar You don't necessarily need to use a monospace font. The 2d canvas context has a [measureText](http://www.w3.org/html/wg/drafts/2dcontext/html5_canvas/#dom-context-2d-measuretext) which will return the width of the text, but it doesn't provide height metrics. One solution is to create a hidden span styled with the same font you want to measure, update the text and get the bounding box of the span. Another alternative is to draw the text to a secondary canvas, then get the bounding box by testing pixels [example](http://mudcu.be/journal/2011/01/html5-typographic-metrics/)

Comment: @KerryLiu I understand I've worked with those methods before but I still prefer monospace fonts to ensure the text lines up and is equal on the right hand side. You can also justify the text to solve that issue but it becomes a matter of preference at that point.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to wrap each character in an element, so it seems that the minimal code is like

```
<a style=color:#123456>x</a>
```

or alternatively

```
<font color=#123456>x</font>
```

for each character x. The codes are of equal length, but in the latter, the number sign '#' can in practice be omitted (it is an error to omit it, but by browser practice and HTML5 drafts, there is error handling that effectively implies the `#` provided that the value does not constitute a color name known to the browser. This is risky, so I would go for the first alternatively.

If the colors are not in fact all different but may repeat, then the use of

```
<a class=¿>x</a>
```

together with CSS definitions like

```
.¿{color:#123456}
```

could result in shorter code. You would then need a class name generator; you could keep the class names to single characters, but care would be needed to make sure that the class selectors will conform to CSS syntax.

Answer (score 2):

I can't realy tell if there is a way to do it into CSS
but here is my code in JavaScript

```
    var textID = document.getElementById("text"); // go and take the Text from the ID
var text = textID.innerHTML; // Take the text from the
var toChange = text.split(""); // Separrate each letter into array
var newText = ""; // buffer text
var aClassName = ["red", "green", "blue"]; // class name that you want
var colorNumber = 0; // counter to loop into your class

for (var i=0, ii=toChange.length; i<ii; i++){
        if(colorNumber == aClassName.length){ // if you reach the end of your class array
        colorNumber = 0; //Set it back to 0
    }
    // Add between each letter the span with your class
    newText += "<span class="+aClassName[colorNumber]+">"+toChange[i]+"<\/span>";
    colorNumber++
}
// Output your text into the web
textID.innerHTML = newText;
```

http://jsfiddle.net/WPSrX/

Answer (score 1):

I am taking the chance of attempting to answer this. This is admittedly not a direct answer, but another way of looking at it that would keep your code to an absolute minimum:
If what you want is a sort of non-intrusive watermark; I would suggest the simplest solution to set opacity on the text, and a text-shadow in the css.
You could try something like this:

```
.myText
{
color: white; (or whatever)
opacity:0.5;
text-shadow:....
}
```

There is a massive amount of options for text shadow; but [here is a generator you can play with.](http://css3gen.com/text-shadow/)

I suppose you could also generate the two colours via javascript, should you wish to alter the colours depending on the image.

Answer (score -1):

You shared no code so there is nothing I can improve upon so the best that can be done is to show you some shorthand CSS and minimal length CSS classes...

**HTML**

```
<span class="r">red</span>
```

**CSS**

```
.r {color: #f00;}
```

Comment: He said that he wanted "distinct color for each character of the text" not for the entire word