# How to print each letter in different color in css /html

Tags: html, css

I want to print "google" on a web page i.e(i want to print each letter in different color but all are in same line)For Example: G is in yellow, o is in blue, o is in red , g is in orange etc.

**Note:using CSS only**

Comment: Isn't this what you need?
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18942818/minimal-html-css-to-specify-distinct-color-for-each-character-of-the-text

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Target one letter in a string with javascript](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29462701/target-one-letter-in-a-string-with-javascript)

Comment: For future reference if you want something in HTML and/or CSS, don't tag your question with JavaScript and jQuery.

Comment: Do you want to do this for a specific word, or an entire page? I can see it working for just a word but the whole page won't be doable for printing only.

Comment: TylerH sorry for the  inconvince.

Comment: #Will ,yeah its for a word "google"  only not for a whole page.

Comment: @Tyrell there are probably an endless amount of ways you could do this. Here's one http://codepen.io/anon/pen/AXQjWJ

Comment: do you want print using javascript code or just a static text you want to color it ?

Comment: yeah i  want,Please help me out #Ein2012

Comment: You could use the nth-child(4n+1) notation to automate this on larger texts. http://codepen.io/RobMo/pen/Wxkbqa

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Use `spans` like this:

```
<p>
  <span style='color: blue'>G</span>
  <span style='color: red'>o</span>
  <span style='color: yellow'>o</span>
  <span style='color: blue'>g</span>
  <span style='color: green'>l</span>
  <span style='color: red'>e</span>
</p>
```

They are just like `p`, `h1` and etc, but they don't go to the next line.

Also, be aware of Google’s usage terms.

Comment: More precise colors:

`<span style='color: #4285f4'>G</span>
<span style='color: #ea4335'>O</span>
<span style='color: #fbbc05'>O</span>
<span style='color: #4285f4'>G</span>
<span style='color: #34a853'>L</span>
<span style='color: #ea4335'>E</span>`

Comment: I get small spaces in between g,o,o,g,l,e. But once I didn't put any spaces between all span tags and got a continuous 'google'. However now the code loogs a bit ugly.

Comment: @matak8s It may be due to putting the `span` elements on separate lines of code. You could also try using "white-space: nowrap" on the CSS for the container (`p` in this case).